# How to align ion-inputs one by one in ion-list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic framework - (Using Ionic framework 3)

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-list inset>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-input name="products" id="" type="text" required></ion-input><br>
                <ion-input name="products" id="" type="text" required></ion-input><br>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Above ionic html code generating input fields side by side. But I want input fields one after the other

Please refer attachment that tells about my issue.

Please guide me through the correct way. Thank you. [Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrBTI.png)

Comment: So "Test 1" and "Test 2" are each ion-items?

Comment: @jonwayne No, Test 1 and Test 2 are two different input fields

Comment: Putting each ion-input in its own ion-item doesn't give you the display you want?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put each input field in a single `ion-item`, as described in the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#inline-labels):

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-list inset>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input name="products" id="" type="text" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input name="products" id="" type="text" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```